# JQuery DataTables get info message

Tags: jquery, datatables

Is it possible to get this info message from data tables through some public method:

Showing 1 to 8 of 35 entries (filtered from 104 total entries)

What I've found is this:

```
$("#myTable_info").text()
```

I can get text through this and hide original DIV with info message. But I guess there is some public method through which I can read info message? I am asking this because I want my own control with info message and not use default one, in the lower left corner.

Comment: what you want to do ? customize the info text or something else ?

Comment: I want to show info message in my own DIV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get the object with the page details using a method from the API called `.page.info()`

So to get this information use one of the methods as described below.

---

Using **.DataTable()**

**1)**
`$('#myTable_info').DataTable().page.info();`

I ran this in the [datatables main landing page](http://www.datatables.net/). And here is the result

[image]

**2)** you can save the `DataTable()` object into a variable when you apply the plugin and then use the `.page.info()` on it.

```
 var myDataTable = $('#myTable_info').DataTable(); // you apply the plugin here.
 var pageInfoObject = myDataTable.page.info();
```

---

Using **.dataTable()**

**3)** when you apply the plugin using `.dataTable()` then to get the page infor you must use the `api()`. like below

```
$('#myTable_info').dataTable().api().page.info();
```

**4)** Or save into a variable and then use the variable to get the info like this.

```
var myDataTable= $('#myTable_info').dataTable();
var info = myDataTable.api().page.info();
```

---

**Edit 1)** after your comment on the other answer

> I just want to show info message in my own DIV. I know how to
>   manipulate it, just don't know how not to use default DIV where this
>   message is displayed (lower left corner)

What you are looking for is to change the **[datatables DOM structure](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom)**.

it would be better if you take some time and understand the logic in the above mention link.

Example : If you want to place the page info on top of the table in a seperate div then this is how you do it. Example here **[Basic Initialization](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html)**

```
   $('#myTable_info').DataTable( {
        "dom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">'
    } );
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to customize info messages you can go through [***Language***](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language) option of DataTable. ***[Info](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.info)*** is used for customizing message.

here is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/qpLtLfaz/129/)

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "language": {
    "info": "Showing page _PAGE_ of _PAGES_",
    "infoEmpty":      "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries",
    "infoPostFix":    "",
    "infoFiltered":   "(filtered from _MAX_ total entries)",
  }
} );
```

**UPDATE** :

for public method to get [***page***](https://datatables.net/reference/event/page) info :

```
var table = $('#example').dataTable();
var info = table.api().page.info();

var table = $('#example').DataTable(); 
var info = table .page.info()
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I just want to show info message in my own DIV. I know how to manipulate it, just don't know how not to use default DIV where this message is displayed (lower left corner).

Comment: @FrenkyB : check updated answer for getting page info